# Angular Observable to Array

Tags: typescript, angular5

The following **does not** output array to console. Scoping incorrect???

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Broker } from './broker';

@Injectable()
export class BrokerSurveyService {

  brokers: Broker[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getBrokers().subscribe((brokers) => { 
      this.brokers = brokers;
    });
    console.log(this.brokers); # Does NOT output to console
  }

  getBrokers() {
    return this.http.get<Broker[]>('http://www.example.com/brokers.json');
  }

}
```

This outputs the array to the console because it sent to console immediate after assignment. Is `this` scope different? I'm confused as to why.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Broker } from './broker';

@Injectable()
export class BrokerSurveyService {

  brokers: Broker[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getBrokers().subscribe((brokers) => { 
      this.brokers = brokers;
      console.log(this.brokers); # Outputs to console
    });
  }

  getBrokers() {
    return this.http.get<Broker[]>('http://www.example.com/brokers.json');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **`correct`**,

Since the service call is asynchronous, the data does not arrive immediately when the subscribe is called. Rather, when the response is returned from the service, the callback function defined as the argument to the subscribe method is then called.

That's why the console.log within the Subscribe works.

If you want to use the array somewhere in your code, call using another method

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getBrokers().subscribe((brokers) => { 
      this.brokers = brokers;
      useBroker(this.brokers);
    });
 }

useBroker(brokers:any){
   console.log(brokers);
}
```